# How to add a \hyperref inside theorem title or proof name

Tags: hyperref

I have a proof that shows many sections after the statement of the theorem and I want the proof to say "Proof of Important Theorem" with a hyperlink to the theorem statement.

I can do it with `\autoref` or `\ref`, but I get "Proof of Theorem 1.0", which is not what I want. I need the name of the theorem in the proof.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] %restarts every section
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Important Theorem]\label{important} this is the theorem
\end{theorem}

%This works, but it's not what I want
\begin{proof}[Proof of \autoref{important}] It's obvious.
\end{proof}

%This one doesn't work
%\begin{proof}[Proof of \hyperref[important]{Important Theorem} ] It's obvious. \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

When I try something like this

`\begin{proof}[Proof of \hyperref[important]{Important Theorem} ] It's obvious. \end{proof}`

I get an error.

Is there a way to manually add `hyperref`'s to the title of a proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `[...]` inside an optional argument is the problem, but you can hide them by wrapping `\hyperref[important]{Important Theorem}` in an additional group of `{...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] %restarts every section
\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}[Important Theorem]\label{important} this is the theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Proof of {\hyperref[important]{Important Theorem}}] It's obvious.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Easy enough and correct. Thank you!

Comment: @user2506946 You're welcome!